# Django collectstatic runs with no errors, however no files are collected - on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a site onto heroku and I'm running into problems with the django collectstatic. 
It was working fine, but it suddenly stopped - I believe after I set some environment variables?

I'm using S3 to upload files too, but letting heroku serve the static files

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
Adding config vars and restarting app... done, v21
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     => xxx
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => yyy
```

In my settings.py:

```python
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_KEY'] 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = <my app)
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_ROOT
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    location('<my app>/static/'),
)
```

When I `push` to heroku it doesn't run collect static anymore

```
$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 385 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Cleaning up...

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 77.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v20
       <my heroku app> deployed to Heroku

To git@<my heroku app>
   5b6f40e..cc69959  master -> master
```

setting `$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` doesn't seem to have an effect

`$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` runs without failing but doesn't have any effect

I also tried finding `staticfiles` in the heroku directory with `heroku run bash` but it doesn't exist

...where are my files going?

Comment: Did you try deploying or running from a non heroku and see if it's related to heroku or your app?

Comment: collect static works just fine locally, and it was working on heroku until a little bit ago.

Comment: You may want to look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320265/can-do-nothing-through-heroku-shell).

Answer (score 0):

It has been long since I deployed to Heroku but I will give a shot.
When I deployed:
-I collected static from my development laptop to Amazon S3 first, and made sure all the static files were copied.
-Then, I pushed my repo to Heroku.
-Now, the python files were served via Heroku, and static files via S3.
-If Debug if False, Django does not serve static locally anyways which you want in your development.
Also:
-You can manually copy the static files to S3 as long as the settings point to the right location.

Hope it helps.